# Should we worship God according to our ability?

Tags: gods, worship, spirituality

I've seen videos on the internet where people are worshiping god, almost all the time... They suggest to do so too... It really makes me uncomfortable, as I am not much spiritual. Is it necessary to do Spirituality most of the time?
My situation is also not suited...

Comment: **Just pray to God whenever you can. Remember him whenever possible for at least a few seconds once in a while. Wherever you are, thank him and praise him with true love and devotion.** If done with very very genuine love and devotion, it is simply pure Bhakti. This is a crore times better than all the Pujas done with no devotion, but simply for the sake of doing it. **Rembering, praying, praising, and thanking him from wherever you are is more than enough! It is also one of the nine types of Bhakti; it is called Smaranam (literally meaning remembering the Lord)**.